# ¿Cómo ocultar o matar un DialogFragment incrustado en una actividad y devolver el foco a la pantalla?

Tags: java, android, diálogo

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente al tratar de ocultar/matar una actividad que se encuentra "lookeada" como un dialogo.

Mi actividad utilizada como un dialogo es inicializada dentro de mi home widget: (Aclaro que al ser un widget, este código y la inicialización de la actividad son llamados desde el escritorio del teléfono)

```
    public class NotusWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    ...


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            //Configuramos los datos a enviar a la dialogactivity
            Intent i = new Intent();
            //Añadimos el id de la nota al intent
            i.putExtra(ConstantUtils.NOTA_KEY, new NotaDAO(context).obtenerNotaById(intent.getIntExtra(NOTA_ID, -1)));
            i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            //Añadimos la clase que tiene el dialogo
            i.setClassName(context.getPackageName(), "com.zulu.notus.widget.WidgetDialogActivity");
            //Configuramos la flag
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            //Iniciamos la actividad
            context.startActivity(i);


    }
```

Este es el código de mi actividad, que se encarga de incorporar un     DialogFragment a su contenido:

```
public class WidgetDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Indicamos que el dialogo no tendria Title
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_confirm_dialog_layout);
    //Ocultamos el contenido
    findViewById(R.id.root).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //Agregamos la nueva vista
    BaseDialog passwordDialogFragment = BaseDialog.newInstance(BaseDialog.DIALOGO_DESBLOQUEAR_NOTA, false,trackerDAO.getIntentosFallidos(notaRecibida.getId()));
    passwordDialogFragment.setmOnLockPasswordClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, passwordDialogFragment).commit();

}}
```

Una vez que mi actividad es inicializada la vista previa del widget y del "dialog activity", es la siguiente:

[image: Previsualizacion del widget con el dialogo]

El problema acontece cuando doy click en el boton cancelar perteneciente al DialogFragment (incrustado en la actividad). Ya que al intentar ocultar o finalizar el dialogo la pantalla queda oscurecida como si algo interfiriera.
El código del evento:

```
public class WidgetDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
@Override
public void onNegativeClick(BaseDialog mDialog) {
//Cerramos la actividad y el dialogo
mDialog.dismiss();
finish();
// He probado con mDialog.onDestroy();
// mDialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}}
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado no deseado (fondo obscuro) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado deseado lo logro obtener cuando el usuario da click en el boton back del celular produciendo que la pantalla vuelva a su tonalidad correspondiente (No es la solución que requiero). Pero no he encontrado solucion para que desde el evento de cancelar la pantalla recupere su tonalidad de modo programático:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código completo del proyecto puede descargarse del [repositorio de github](https://github.com/zulu15/Notus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con estas opciones:

```
 tuActivity.this.finish();
```

**ó**

Dentro de tu `onNegativeClick`:

```
mDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
mDialog.dismiss();
finish();
```

Comment: En realidad era un problema con los listeners mi onNegativeClick estaba siendo seteado pero nunca llamado ya que dentro de mi DialogFragment nunca hacía el llamado pero había una acción por defecto que ejecutaba el dismiss !. Te acepto la respuesta como correcta de todas formas. Gracias por tu tiempo. Saludos!